# A possible generalization of the Borsuk Ulam theorem via action of symmetric groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, group-actions

The symmetric  group $S_{m}$ is  equiped with the  counting  Har measure $\mu$ and the  obvious  sgn  character. Assume  that $S_{m}$ acts on $S^{n}$, $n\geq m-1$  and  $f:S^{n}\to  \mathbb{R}^{n}$  is  a  continuous map.

> Is  it  true  to  say  that  there exist $x_{0}\in S^{n}$  such that
>   $$  \int_{S_{m}} sgn(g)f(g.x_{0})d\mu=0    $$
>   In the other word: Is there a  point $x_{0}\in S^{n}$ such that
>   $$ \sum_{g\in A_{n}} f(g.x_{0})= \sum_{g\notin A_{n}} f(g.x_{0})    $$
>   where $A_{n}$ is  the group of even permutations?

**Note 1:** In this  question the  action is  arbitrary but continuous, so  we  dont consider a  particular action.

**Motivations:**  The  answer is affirmative in each  of the  following  cases:

1.$m=2$ (The original  Borsuk  Ulam theorem or its  involutive  version)

2.If  we  replace  the  statement "$f:S^{n}\to  \mathbb{R}^{n}$"  with "$f:S^{n}\to R^{2}$".

3.Every  action with singularity,  for  example  the  obvious  action of  $S_{m}$  on $S^{m-1}.$

**Note 2:** A  natural question related to this  post could be "To what  extent, the  action of  permutation groups on spheres is  classified"? Of course there is  a  non  singular  action of  $S_{m}$ on $S^{m-1}$  with $sgn(g)g.x$ where $g.x$ is  the  obvious  action.