# Free action of symmetric groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

> What  type  of  compact  manifolds,   can be acted  freely  by symmetric  group $S_{m}$  for  some  $m>2$?
>
> Is  there  a  compact manifold  which  can be  act  freely by  all  symmetric  groups $S_{m}$?

This  question have  been  asked  already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981053/free-action-of-symmetric-group)
and  is  indirectly related to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184814/a-possible-generalization-of-the-borsuk-ulam-theorem-via-action-of-symmetric-gro).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the second question is more or less no by Theorem 2 in Popov's [Finite subgroups of diffeomorphism groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6548): for every compact connected smooth manifold $M$ there is a constant $b_M$ such that if the alternating group $A_n$ acts (by diffeomorphisms, but not necessarily freely) on $M$, then $n \le b_M$.

I don't really understand what kind of answer you're expecting to the first question.

Comment: Thank you for your  answer.  To start, I search for  an example of a free action. then  a  possible  classification. regarding your answer, what about continuous action?

Comment: Writing down examples is straightforward but I don't understand what kind of classification you're expecting. Somewhat more generally, let $M$ be a compact manifold, $G$ be a finite group, and $f : \pi_1(M) \to G$ be a surjective homomorphism; for example, we can always take $M$ to be a surface of sufficiently large genus. Then $f$ is the classifying map of a principal $G$-bundle on $M$ which is a compact manifold on which $G$ acts freely with quotient $M$. It is connected iff $M$ is. Every connected example arises in this way.

Comment: $M$ the frame bundle of a high-dimensional sphere would work, as well. You could ensure the action is free in this setting.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Could  you please  give  a  reference for your  statements.(whare i can find  such  materials?) by  classification I mean some thing  as  follows:  for the  moment  lets forget "Free". We are interested to know  about  all  actions of $S_{m}$ on $S^{m-1}$. Are there only a  finite  number of  such  actions  up to topological equivalent?

Comment: @RyanBudney  How  permutation group act?

Comment: If you think of the symmetric group as the group of motions of the $n$-simplex, the boundary of the $n$-simplex is canonically a smoothly-triangulated sphere.  So the symmetry group is a group of diffeomorphisms of an $(n-1)$-sphere.  It does not act freely on that sphere, but it does act freely on the unit tangent bundle, since these symmetries are isometries in the appropriate spherical riemann metric on the sphere.